# Make heroku completely use my github repository

Tags: github, heroku

I use SQLite(I am required to use this database), but when I update the source code and push to heroku's git, the database content is empty again. So how can I not use heroku's git and only use github repo as my heroku app's storage?

Or it is better to make git not push the database file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Um, you have a problem as Heroku doesn't really support SQLite, by default it uses a Postgres database. Issue is that changes to the directory the rails app uses in heroku are not saved long term for performance/scaling reasons (basically whenever you restart the server, all previous data is wiped).

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

The real question is why do you need to use the SQLite database and how it used outside of your rails app?

You could export the SQLite database content to CSVs or some other database-independant format which can then be used to seed the database after you push to heroku.

The problems start is if you need to get changes to that database back into the SQLite database...